# Problems connecting to MongoDB server from MongoLab

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to connect to mongodb created by MongoLab, but it always seems to fail.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds123854.mongolab.com:12345/the_db');

mongoose.connection.on('open', function (ref) {
  console.log('Connected to mongo server.');
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('Could not connect to mongo server!');
  console.log(err);
});

// check if mongoose connected; 0 = no; 1 = yes; 2 = connecting; 4 = disconnecting
console.log("mongoose connection: " + mongoose.connection.readyState);
```

I get the log:

```
mongoose connection: 2
Could not connect to mongo server!
{ [MongoError: auth failed] name: 'MongoError', ok: 0, errmsg: 'auth failed', code: 18 }
```

I tried to check the password, so I did the following in my console:

```
> mongo ds123854.mongolab.com:12345/the_db -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7
connecting to: ds123854.mongolab.com:12345/the_db
rs-ds123854:PRIMARY> db.mynewcollection.insert({ "foo": "bar"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
rs-ds123854:PRIMARY> db.mynewcollection.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("563c1913504f0ab5cb96d74c"), "foo" : "bar" }
```

The username and password seem right and I can see that the insert command did put something into the database.
I am hosting my server in localhost, so I believe that's the problem. What sort of things am I missing in my configuration?

Comment: String seems fine to me : https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/
Did you check your mongo accept remote connection ? Are you sure you're not doing something wrong with port or user/password ?

Comment: I believe that I'm using the right user/password. If I connect from my terminal, it seems to work fine. The trouble seems to be when trying to connect from my server in localhost

Comment: Check conf, maybe you have bind on localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Ensure that your version of Mongoose is up to date.

In my case, I was using version *3.6.13*, but the current version is *4.2.4*

If you specified your mongoose version, just update your `package.json` file and use command line `npm update`